# javascript check if java enabled in IE WITHOUT running jar

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, browser-detection

I wanna detect if java is enabled in a browser without running any jars.I did this in Chrome and Firefox with the navigator.plugins and it's working great, but in IE its returning always true.Any ideas?Thanx in advance.

Comment: We check it via a callback. If the Applet is not running, no callback is called -> definitievly not enabled. But we can not distinguish between not enabled and not running.

Comment: I know this.Im asking something different.